# Go: информация о файле

Tags: golang

Как получить подробную информацию о файле в Go, в том числе дату создания, дату последнего изменения?

```
files, err := ioutil.ReadDir("C:\\Windows\\System32")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("error")
}

for _, file := range files {
    if file.IsDir() == false {
        fmt.Printf("%s --- %d\n", file.Name(), file.Size())
    }
}
```

Comment: package "os", type FileInfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обо всём, что кроссплатформенно, расскажет тип [`os.FileInfo`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo). Дальше уже всё непереносимо. Пример на OS GNU/Linux:

```
f, err := os.Open("foo.txt")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("open: %v", err)
}
defer f.Close()

stat, err := f.Stat()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("stat: %v", err)
}

log.Printf("file %q: size: %d, mod. time: %q", stat.Name(), stat.Size(), stat.ModTime())
log.Printf("file sys: %T", stat.Sys())

sysstat := stat.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t)
log.Printf("file %q: access time: %d, mod. time: %d, change time: %d", stat.Name(), sysstat.Atim.Nano(), sysstat.Mtim.Nano(), sysstat.Ctim.Nano())
```